# Ubutnu 20.04 fresh install / no bootable device

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi, dell-latitude

I have recently installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 from a live USB completely formatting my hard drive. However, the installed OS does not register with the UEFI and it does not even try to boot -- fails with an error message "no bootable devices found".

My laptop is Dell Latitute 5490. Secure boot is turned off. In bios settings, next to UEFI the boot sequence is empty. I can still boot from live USB. Here is the boot-repair log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dFWRx6tp5z/.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I have found the following answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913397/how-to-change-ubuntu-install-from-legacy-to-uefi. The issues was that my live USB only boots in BIOS mode (rather than UEFI) and thus incorrectly installs Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed Ubuntu20.04 on two laptops and had the same problem there. For Lenovo laptop I changed legacy BIOS to UEFI(for this I gave 1GB for efi during partition) and enabled secure boot it worked, for older HP laptop I installed it on Legacy BIOS and gave 1GB for /boot during partition.